# How to Skip all the characters from string after occurance of particular character

Tags: c++, string, set

in below programme, I need to insert string till '|' character in set .

but after erasing charcter '|' in my code , I am not able to skip all the character till the end.

input: +919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320|9845012345, +91987654321, 0987654320, 987654323, 987654320

expected output: +919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320

Note: (1) after entering the data , type exit .
      (2) substring function can't be used for this purpose.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string str;
string::iterator it;
unordered_set <string> s;


while(getline(cin,str)) //
    {
        if(str=="exit")
        {
              break;
        }

        for (it= str.begin(); it !=str.end(); it++)
        {
            if (*it =='|')
            {
                it = str.erase(it);

             }


        }
    s.insert(str);


    }


for ( unordered_set<string> ::const_iterator  itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); ++itr) {
    cout<<*itr<<endl;
}

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using string::find_first_of
see here:
*http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/*

Use the above function to find the index of the next delimiter "|" and create a string from the range (substring).
This method is also very fast compared to the alternatives.
Another option is to use C's strtok on a copy of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing too difficult..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myString = "+919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320|9845012345, +91987654321, 0987654320, 987654323, 987654320";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; (myString[i] != '|') && (i < myString.length()); i++)
        cout << myString[i];
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but i can't use same string to insert in set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the code

```
    for (it= str.begin(); it !=str.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it =='|')
        {
            it = str.erase(it);

         }


    }
```

try to use

```
str.erase( str.find( '|' ) );
```

Demonstrative example

```
    std::string s = "+919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320|9845012345, +91987654321, 0987654320, 987654323, 987654320";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    s.erase( s.find( '|' ) );
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Output is

```
+919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320|9845012345, +91987654321, 0987654320, 98765
4323, 987654320
+919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320
```

Comment: It does work. For example for your input string you will get that str will be equal to  +919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320

Comment: Thanks it works fine, earlier I thought I need to replace the code inside loop so it was my mistake .

Comment: can we also erase the data in same manner if we want to erase the content before '|' sign. so output should be :9845012345, +91987654321, 0987654320, 98765
4323, 987654320
+919845012345, 0987654321, 987654320